# Video from Url in Videoview

Tags: android

I want to play a video from a url in a VideoView:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String path1="http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp";
    Uri uri=Uri.parse(path1);

    VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    video.setVideoURI(uri);
    video.start();
}
```

But I'm getting a NullPointerException when I try to run the app.

The logcat says that the problem is in: `video.setVideoURI(uri);`

Can someone help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you are defining a layout... I think you forgot:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Which would cause any findViewById() to return null.

Comment: Ok, that was the problem :-).

Comment: Is it also possible to play mp4 files? If i try to play such a file i'm getting this message: Could not play video".

Comment: [Android supports mp4](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), but I just tried with a random mp4 and got the same vague pop-up error... Sorry, I don't know the answer to this one off the top of my head.